# ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pydna: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, swig, maya, unreal-engine5, quixel-bridge

Update: I traced the line which is causing the problem.

[image]

Error is coming from dna.py file, from line code 15.

This is the code:

```
    # Import the low-level C/C++ module
if __package__ or '.' in __name__:
    from . import _pydna
else:
    import _pydna
```

if is never true. I printed __ Package __ it prints nothing. it is empty. I printed __ Name __ it prints "dna".

from what I can gather. it's not finding my current folder that _pydna is located in. I don't understand the code fully, but I know python swig generated it and this is what Swig uses to import modules.

I don't understand where else statement is supposed to import _pydna from. Am I supposed to pip install it somewhere?

---

Import Error: DLL load failed while importing _pydna: The specified module could not be found.
This is the error I am getting in Autodesk Maya console.
I want to export my Meta Human from Quixel Bridge, I have exported my Meta Human with UAsset + Source Asset as their documentation suggested. Export is shown to be successful. But nothing appears in Maya. I have checked the console, and this is the error I am getting:

Import Error: DLL load failed while importing _pydna: The specified module could not be found.

I am using Windows 11 and Maya 2024 student version.

Full Console Log:

```
file -f -new;
// untitled
commandPort -securityWarning -name commandportDefault;
onSetCurrentLayout "General";
# DHI.modules.maya.util : Preparing paths and loading DHI Plugins
# DHI.modules.maya.util : Running on Windows 
Importing DHI external libraries
# DHI.modules.maya.util : Running Maya version 2017
# DHI.modules.maya.util : Fetching libraries from folder D:/Quixel Bridge/Megascans Library/support/plugins/maya/7.0/MSLiveLink/DHI/lib/Windows/python2
# DHI.modules.maya.util : Lib folder not on path... Adding
# DHI.modules.maya.util : Running on Windows 
# modules.maya.util : Running Maya version 2017
Loading plugin:  D:/Quixel Bridge/Megascans Library/support/plugins/maya/7.0/MSLiveLink/DHI/plugins/Windows/2017/embeddedRL4.mll
Error loading plugin embeddedRL4
Loading plugin:  D:/Quixel Bridge/Megascans Library/support/plugins/maya/7.0/MSLiveLink/DHI/plugins/Windows/2017/MayaUE4RBFPlugin2017.mll
Error loading plugin MayaUE4RBFPlugin2017
Loading plugin:  D:/Quixel Bridge/Megascans Library/support/plugins/maya/7.0/MSLiveLink/DHI/plugins/Windows/2017/MayaUERBFPlugin.mll
Error loading plugin MayaUERBFPlugin
saveShelf MSPlugin "C:/Users/Danish Nazir Arain/Documents/maya/2024/prefs/shelves/shelf_MSPlugin";
// 1
Quixel Bridge Plugin started successfully.
// Bifrost: Pre-loaded mayaUsdPlugin to access proper Maya USD libraries.
// Loading Bifrost version 2.7.0.0-202302170226-ac4d174
// Bifrost: Loading library: Amino, from: Autodesk.
// Bifrost: Loading library: AminoMayaTranslation, from: Autodesk.
// Bifrost: Loading library: bif, from: Autodesk.
// Bifrost: Loading library: bifrostObjectMayaTranslations, from: Autodesk.
// Bifrost: Loading library: geometries, from: Autodesk.
// Bifrost: Loading library: fluids, from: Autodesk.
// Bifrost: Loading library: particles, from: Autodesk.
// Bifrost: Loading library: file, from: Autodesk.
// Bifrost: Loading library: mpm, from: Autodesk.
// Bifrost: Loading library: modeling, from: Autodesk.
// Bifrost: Loading library: nucleus, from: Autodesk.
// Bifrost: Loading library: simulation, from: Autodesk.
// Bifrost: Loading library: riv_types, from: Autodesk.
// Bifrost: Loading library: riv, from: Autodesk.
// Bifrost: Loading library: scatter_pack, from: Autodesk.
// Bifrost: Loading library: graphs, from: Autodesk.
// Bifrost: Loading library: usd_pack, from: Autodesk.
// Bifrost: Loading library: usdMayaTranslations, from: Autodesk.
// Warning: file: C:\Users\Danish Nazir Arain\Documents\maya\2024\prefs\filePathEditorRegistryPrefs.mel line 4: filePathEditor: Attribute 'aiImage.filename' is invalid or is not designated 'usedAsFilename'.
// Warning: file: C:\Users\Danish Nazir Arain\Documents\maya\2024\prefs\filePathEditorRegistryPrefs.mel line 5: filePathEditor: Attribute 'aiPhotometricLight.aiFilename' is invalid or is not designated 'usedAsFilename'.
// Warning: file: C:\Users\Danish Nazir Arain\Documents\maya\2024\prefs\filePathEditorRegistryPrefs.mel line 6: filePathEditor: Attribute 'aiStandIn.dso' is invalid or is not designated 'usedAsFilename'.
// Warning: file: C:\Users\Danish Nazir Arain\Documents\maya\2024\prefs\filePathEditorRegistryPrefs.mel line 7: filePathEditor: Attribute 'aiVolume.filename' is invalid or is not designated 'usedAsFilename'.
// AbcExport v1.0 using Alembic 1.8.3 (built Feb 17 2023 07:53:30)
evalDeferred "shaderBallRendererMenuUpdate";
// Warning: line 1: filePathEditor: Attribute 'aiStandIn.dso' and label 'Standin' have been saved already.
// Warning: line 1: filePathEditor: Attribute 'aiVolume.filename' and label 'VDB' have been saved already.
// Warning: line 1: filePathEditor: Attribute 'aiImage.filename' and label 'Image' have been saved already.
// Warning: line 1: filePathEditor: Attribute 'aiPhotometricLight.aiFilename' and label 'IES' have been saved already.
import arnold
import mtoa
import mtoa.cmds.registerArnoldRenderer;mtoa.cmds.registerArnoldRenderer.registerArnoldRenderer()
updateRenderOverride;
import mtoa.viewport;mtoa.viewport.add_controls()
// AbcImport v1.0 using Alembic 1.8.3 (built Feb 17 2023 07:53:30)
updateRendererUI;
file -f -new;
// untitled
Found import data, importing...
Analytics Sent
Received data with DH Character descriptor. Initializing import!
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "D:\Quixel Bridge\Megascans Library\support\plugins\maya\7.0\MSLiveLink\LiveLink.py", line 124, in InitializeImporter
#     from DHI.DHIImporterSetup import DHIImporterSetup
#   File "D:\Quixel Bridge\Megascans Library\support\plugins\maya\7.0\MSLiveLink\DHI\DHIImporterSetup.py", line 8, in <module>
#     from DHI.modules.dna.scene.builder.sceneBuilder import SceneBuilder, SceneBuilderError
#   File "D:\Quixel Bridge\Megascans Library\support\plugins\maya\7.0\MSLiveLink\DHI\modules\dna\scene\builder\sceneBuilder.py", line 7, in <module>
#     from DHI.modules.dna.dnaprovider import DNAProvider
#   File "D:\Quixel Bridge\Megascans Library\support\plugins\maya\7.0\MSLiveLink\DHI\modules\dna\dnaprovider.py", line 5, in <module>
#     from DHI.modules.dna.dnaholder import DNAHolder
#   File "D:\Quixel Bridge\Megascans Library\support\plugins\maya\7.0\MSLiveLink\DHI\modules\dna\dnaholder.py", line 1, in <module>
#     import dna
#   File "D:\Quixel Bridge/Megascans Library/support/plugins/maya/7.0/MSLiveLink/DHI/lib/Windows/python2\dna.py", line 15, in <module>
#     import _pydna
# ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pydna: The specified module could not be found.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quixel Bridge for now doesn't support Maya 2024. [Quixel FAQs](https://help.quixel.com/hc/en-us/articles/360002073717-Which-DCCs-and-render-engines-can-I-export-assets-to-via-Quixel-Bridge-with-the-Plugins-)

https://help.quixel.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/11225123454109-Import-Error-DLL-load-failed-while-importing-pydna-The-specified-module-could-not-be-found-From-Quixel-Bridge-to-Maya-Export-